# Do .Where linq queries on lists fail inside static methods? (no, delayed evaluation)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq

Running in debug mode in Visual Studio. I do not use filteredResults later in code, the line is there in order for me to find all cases where results has something true about it, but it is simple "the Result class has a property and I want to see all items where that property is true" sort of stuff.

I put a breakpoint on the open bracket of the where statement and it does not hit it, SomeFilter was a static bool method, right now I have the code directly in the where statement, does not matter. If I set a breakpoint on NextLine (a stand in) it hits, and I can look inside the results list. filteredResults always evaluates to "enumeration did not yield any results"... even if I filter by something that would be true for a Result I can see in the debugger in results.

The only thing I can think of is maybe the fact that it is called in a static method is somehow preventing the enumeration from evaluating, but I only think that because I cannot see anything else that would cause this.

```
public static void FilterResults(List<Result> results)
{
        var filteredResults = results.Where(c =>
        {
            bool filterTrue = SomeFilter(c);

            return filterTrue;
        });

        NextLine()
 }
```

Comment: Why not just make this an extension method where T : Result?

Comment: How are you using `this` in a static method?

Comment: The code in the `Where` is not evaluated until you iterate `filteredResults` which you don't seem to do in this example.

Comment: @itsme86 There is no "this" (oops)

Comment: I wonder if I should edit the name of the question given that  the method being static had nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filter function is not getting executed because evaluation of `filteredResults` is *deferred*. You never call `ToList()` on it or enumerate it in any other way, so the result that would have enumerated through the collection is simply dropped.

If you want the condition to get hit, call `ToList()` on the result:

```
var filteredResults = results.Where(c =>
{
    bool filterTrue = SomeFilter(c);
    return filterTrue;
}).ToList();
```

Note that you could also change the method to return `filteredResults` without calling `ToList`, in which case the breakpoint would be hit each time the caller enumerates the returned sequence:

```
public static IEnumerable<Result> FilterResults(List<Result> results) {
    var filteredResults = results.Where(c => {
        bool filterTrue = SomeFilter(c);
        return filterTrue;
    });
    NextLine();
    return filteredResults;
}
...
foreach (var res in FilterResults(results)) {
    ... // The condition inside FilterResults method would get hit each time the loop iterates
}
```

Comment: So I guess there is some other reason it is not yielding results when I don't see how that is possible. I'll try calling .ToList() and debugging the result, thanks to you and nvoight.

Answer (score 4):

It's called "deferred execution" and basically means "if you don't enumerate the result of an `IEnumerable<T>` it will not execute. It will only execute if you *make* it execute, by using the result (for example in a `foreach` or something that uses it under the hood like `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()`.